# Backgroundimg url not changing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, brackets

```js
window.onload = myFunction;

function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "url (../img/Background2.jpg)";
```

//This function is to change the backgroundimg on launch
    }

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url(../img/Background2.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
```

Comment: You need to define the height.

Comment: Add height and width to your banner id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the space between `url` and `(` in the JS.

So the line:

```
document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "url (../img/fff.png)";
```

Needs to become:

```
document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/fff.png)";
```

Here's a working example:

```js
window.onload = myFunction;

function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById('banner').style.backgroundImage = "url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x350)";

//This function is to change the backgroundimg on launch
}
```

```css
#banner {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Comment: I want to thank you a 10000000 times. This worked thank you very much. I will accept as answer when I can.

Comment: Spaces aren't issue, doesn't matter how many, the point is in the height.

Comment: @Vxp - It doesn't work with the space there. I tested it before I posted the answer.

Comment: Only if I add spaces to both, JS and CSS, I don't get the image, otherwise I do.